# download csv (or other non html data) with phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

How can I access simple csv data?

```
    var webpage = require('webpage');
    var csvPage = webpage.create();
    var csvUrl= "http://www.scoach.ch/arcmsdownload/023c5c5aa58e6e0ff963ddcdea5ac016/CONTENT.csv/derivatives_2013-05-24.csv";

    csvPage.open(csvUrl, function(status){
      console.log("csv: " + csvPage.content);
    });
```

This will give me just an empty html:  which is not the expected result :-) I have tried several callbacks, but nothing helped me.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll just quickly point out that PhantomJS is overkill for this job. Use wget, curl, PHP file_get_contents, etc. However, I'm assuming this is part of a more complicated PhantomJS script, and you have a good reason.

I can only half answer your question, by showing you how to see the missing error messages:

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var csvPage = webpage.create();
var csvUrl= "http://www.scoach.ch/arcmsdownload/023c5c5aa58e6e0ff963ddcdea5ac016/CONTENT.csv/derivatives_2013-05-24.csv";
csvPage.open(csvUrl, function(status){
  console.log("status="+status);
  console.log("csv: " + csvPage.plainText);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I made these changes:

1. Show the status (it is "fail")
2. Change to use `plainText` instead of `content`. (The latter wraps your content in html tags, which you don't want for csv).
3. Add `phantom.exit()`, just so it doesn't sit there at the end.

I don't know *why* the status is "fail", when I can get the file fine with `wget`. The next troubleshooting step is to add these two lines before calling `csvPage.open`:

```
csvPage.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
    console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
csvPage.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
```

It is returning immediately, with 3878 bytes, even though I see a Content-Length header of 6,335,428. This might be a PhantomJS bug/limitation with either chunked encoding or very large files.

UPDATE: Another idea, for a short-term solution, is to call wget or curl from inside your PhantomJS script, using the new spawn or execFile commands:  http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/source/browse/examples/child_process-examples.js

Comment: Thanks! I have sumitted a bug report based on this question.

Answer (score 0):

[This SO post might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915609/how-to-write-to-csv-file-in-javascript). 
Also note that PhantomJS is a separate web server from NodeJS, so using csv node libraries isn't an option.