# How to write to CSV file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, jenkins, phantomjs

I have a script (using PhantomJS) that tests how long it takes to load a webpage. What I am trying to figure out is how to write the result of time taken to load the page to a .csv file. Then if I were to re-run the test again for it to add another result to the .csv file.

code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    t, address;
var pageLoadArray = [];
var csvContents = "";
fs = require('fs');

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    t = Date.now();
    address = system.args[1];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        } 
        else {
            t = Date.now() - t;
            console.log('Page title is ' + page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.title;
            }));

            if(t>7000){
                console.log('Loading time was too long... ' + t + "msec");
                pageLoadArray.push(t);
                console.log(pageLoadArray.length);
                console.log(pageLoadArray[0]);
                //store the time value to the .csv file
                phantom.exit(1);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
                pageLoadArray.push(t);
                console.log(pageLoadArray.length);
                console.log(pageLoadArray[0]);
                //store the time value to the .csv file
            }
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [fs](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) module with the `write(path, content, mode)` method in append mode.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.write(filepath, content, 'a');
```

where `filepath` is the file path as a string and `content` is a string containing your CSV line.

Something like:

```
address+";"+(new Date()).getTime()+";"+t
```

Comment: With node 6.x, it's now `fs.writeFileSync(filepath,content,'a');`

Comment: Oh my bad, did not notice it was using PhantomJS. Forget my comment then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the Jenkins environment, you can use one of the browser specific methods of triggering a download like suggested in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

```
function download(strData, strFileName, strMimeType) {
    var D = document,
        A = arguments,
        a = D.createElement("a"),
        d = A[0],
        n = A[1],
        t = A[2] || "text/plain";

    //build download link:
    a.href = "data:" + strMimeType + "charset=utf-8," + escape(strData);

    if (window.MSBlobBuilder) { // IE10
        var bb = new MSBlobBuilder();
        bb.append(strData);
        return navigator.msSaveBlob(bb, strFileName);
    } /* end if(window.MSBlobBuilder) */

    if ('download' in a) { //FF20, CH19
        a.setAttribute("download", n);
        a.innerHTML = "downloading...";
        D.body.appendChild(a);
        setTimeout(function() {
            var e = D.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);
            D.body.removeChild(a);
        }, 66);
        return true;
    }; /* end if('download' in a) */

    //do iframe dataURL download: (older W3)
    var f = D.createElement("iframe");
    D.body.appendChild(f);
    f.src = "data:" + (A[2] ? A[2] : "application/octet-stream") + (window.btoa ? ";base64" : "") + "," + (window.btoa ? window.btoa : escape)(strData);
    setTimeout(function() {
        D.body.removeChild(f);
    }, 333);
    return true;
}
```

Maybe you can use [this URL SCM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URL+SCM) Plugin to grab the download.
Or use Selenium to automate some things and grab the download file

Comment: I think you've got the wrong question here. This is not a download issue.